# Ubuntu 14.04 Customize Kernel With Keyboard Support (Restart On Typing)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, kernel

I made a customized kernel by using [these instructions](https://github.com/arjun024/mkeykernel). When I run the file on Qemu it run perfectly and shows what I type. But I want to run it from GRUB. I added a menuentry in `grub.cfg` like this

```
menuentry 'Kernel By Me' {
set root ='hd0,msdos7'
multiboot /boot/kernel-01 ro
}
```

now when I select my menuentry 'Kernel By Me' from grub it shows this screen [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6BJo.png) But when I press any key it restarts the computer. I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is what you are supposed to get according to [this page](https://github.com/arjun024/mkeykernel). What exactly did you expect?

Comment: I get this correctly on qemu,
But when I load It From Grub It Show Me The Screen And When I Type It Get Restart I Want To Run It From Grub Too.

Comment: You may need to contact the developer, and ask what is wrong, unless there are error messages, or anything to work with.

Comment: The developer is not available, if you have any files or technique to make a keyboard supported kernel can you provide a link or some reference ?